# Can sign up/log in be unified in one button?

Tags: forms, gui-design, ux-field

I'm working a form at the moment and was consider merging sign in and sign up but thought it might be confusing. Is there any precedent for this?

**Example**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5fYCa.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This has been asked before but the answer was more about the word selection and pointed to [this article](http://uxmovement.com/buttons/why-sign-up-and-sign-in-button-labels-confuse-users/) which I thought was a bit off the point.

Or alternatively, what if the button was dynamic i.e. if the email address was recognised they'd see a button saying 'Log in' but if it wasn't then it would say 'Sign Up':

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpEs2S.png)</sup>

Comment: Related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/79692/email-registered-by-someone-else-first-time-login-register/79699#79699

Comment: @chris, this solution is a little strange... You fill out the form, then the button changes text? Why? That adds way too much into the process. What if the password was mistyped? How is the error message shown? Do they have to click twice to go from continue to log in? This is too confusing in my opinion.

Comment: just thinking of odd solutions to a problem and wondering if anyone had experience of them working or not etc

Comment: The question was definitely interesting, but I could definitely foresee issues with that design pattern. Never hurts to try something new, but sometimes what isn't broken doesn't need fixing ;-)

Comment: See also [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/107268/57088)

Comment: the reason you don't want to do this is information leakage: you don't (generally) want people to be able to use a web form to determine who your users are. i could write a script to try email addresses from some large dataset and learn which of them have an account with your site. i know this is not always a concern, but it's something to be aware of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think combining the two will be confusing. The reason why companies create two distinct paths is because those two **are** different paths.

What happens if someone thinks they have an account, and then when they don't and they start registering and they don't want that, what then? This is forcing a user to register if they don't have a login, and that's not a good idea.

Instead, just create two different paths:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvv22x.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Or worse, what if they have an account, but make a typo in their email address/username? They'll have created a new account without realizing it and all of the stuff they expect to see upon logging in will be missing.

Comment: thanks, I have expanded on the question a little in relation to what you guys have said @NathanRabe and Majo0od

Comment: @Chris I don't think the edit changes the answer. Users are not likely to notice a small change in the text, and many might use the Enter key instead of looking at and clicking the button. There's also no way to guarantee that you can make a round trip to the server to verify the email before the user finishes typing their password and submits the form.

Comment: @NathanRabe completely agree.

Comment: yeah that was what I ended up thinking cause you couldn't exactly preload the email list in the background as the security would be totally compromised haha